# Web with 2 angularjs project

Tags: angularjs

I want to make angularjs project name A and B,
But i want B will be inside A,
I ask my developer and he said just build those 2 and put it together, 
But when i do that, it keep have this error 
[image]

So basically it looks like this:

I grunt build project A and B and make this structure:

Project A
-css
-js
-scripts
-styles
-views
-index.html
-home.html
-BProject

- css
- js
- scripts
- styles
- views
- home.html
- index.html

And when i try to go to www.a.com/b/index.html, it making that error, 
Anyone know what is wrong?
Do i need to change the app.js for both routing?
I'm using html5 mode for those 2 project.

Comment: just by looking at the error wont get much idea, but from the way of the look, it seem that it jquery.js not found

Comment: so, i try to add base_url to my index, and it can load the page, but when i reload the page, it saying 404 not found, do you have any idea for this?

Comment: sorry that i cant help much, there r lots of reason it happen as what you had mention, the only way is to debug through the project

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, this article help me to setting my project. 
I just need to add `<base href="/bproject/"></base>`
and set my nginx configuration :)

Link : 
http://ajbogh.blogspot.kr/2015/05/setting-up-angularjs-html5-mode-in.html

Hope it can help you guys too :)